# Systemd dbus interfaces for suspend and resume notification

Tags: suspend, systemd, dbus

Could anyone let me know the interfaces that can be used to get notification of "resume" once device is resumed from suspend state.

I did have a look at the systemd documentation of logind, but couldn't get complete info on the interface to be used.
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/org.freedesktop.login1.html#